# Custom Project Type Templates

Tags: webstorm, project-template, file-structure, ide-customization

When you create a new project in WebStorm, you are given the option to create a new directory structure prepopulated with files: libraries, stylesheets, etc. for patterns like HTM5 boilerplate, Twitter boilerplate, etc.

How does one create one's own template for this? Is importing dummy projects the hack for it?

Comment: AFAIK list of supported project templates is hard-coded as it requires some special support form IDE for each of such template. Currently IDE does not support user's own project templates.

Comment: Thanks for info - I had the same question. Really would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest not using templates. I find it far more easy and maintainable to create "empty" projects (from existing projects, of course) in a git repo (bitbucket, github, ...), clone one, and start from there.

The `.idea` should be in the repo, but `.idea/workspace.xml` should be ignored, as per the documentation.

This gives you the opportunity to gradually refine your template, and share it easily with a team.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [LivePlugin](https://github.com/dkandalov/live-plugin) plugin to create a project template:

```
<projectTemplate projectType="foo" templatePath="resources/bar.zip" category="true"/>
```

Use the Velocity Template Language (VTL) to create a file template:

> File and code templates are written in the Velocity Template Language (VTL). So they may include:

```
Fixed text (markup, code, comments, etc.).
```

> In a file based on a template, the fixed text is used literally, as-is.

```
File template variables.
```

> When creating a file, the variables are replaced with their values.
>       #parse directives to include other templates defined in the Includes tab on the File and Code Templates page of the Settings dialog box.

```
Other VTL constructs.
```

**References**

- [Create project template extensions using "user defined" templates](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5529278#5529278)
- [Creation of Extension to applicationConfigurable](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Customizing+the+IDEA+Settings+Dialog)
- [IdeaPlugin.xml](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/resources/src/META-INF/IdeaPlugin.xml)
- [PlatformExtensionPoints.xml](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-resources/src/META-INF/PlatformExtensionPoints.xml)
- [LivePlugin: Plugin for writing IDE plugins](https://github.com/dkandalov/live-plugin)
- [Webstorm Help: File and Code Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/file-and-code-templates.html)
- [Configuring JetBrains WebStorm for UI5 development](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/09/22/configuring-jetbrains-webstorm-for-ui5-development)
- [Webstorm Project and IDE Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/project-and-ide-settings.html)
- [Idea NodeJS Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098?pr=idea)
- [Apache Velocity Engine VTL Reference](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html)