# Project type for Sails.js is not getting in Webstorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, sails.js

I am a beginner in using WebStorm. I try to create a new application WebStorm with Jade template engine with node.js and sail.js. I found some project templates in WebStorm "Create New Project" wizard. Please see the below image.

[image]

But I didn't see the **Node.js Sail App** item in my menu. I already installed Sails.js using the command line. How do I get this template in my Project Type menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257425/custom-project-type-templates) and [this ticket on the developer's site](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60187), the project template types are hard-coded into WebStorm and there's no way to make your own.  However, starting a new project in Sails is super easy--just do `sails new [your app name]` on the command line to create a new app with the correct folder structure and files, and [import the app directory into WebStorm!](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-a-project-from-existing-local-sources.html)

Comment: What about the server option.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [Sails/Treeline plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7739) for WebStorm that allows you to directly create a Sails app.  Install the plugin and you can create a new Sails app.